# np.apply_along_axis returning multiple values

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, lambda

I am applying some functions to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
MATRIX=np.random.rand(5,7)


def F_a(x):
   return 1

def F_b(x):
   return [1,2]
FUNCS=[F_a,F_b]

results=list(map(lambda f:np.apply_along_axis(f,1, MATRIX),FUNCS))
```

when all FUNCS return one-scalar value, then it works as expected.
However, **some** of my FUNC return iterables (e.g. variabile lenght lists).

How to apply functions returning multiple values in this manner (map + apply_along_axis)?

If I run the MVE, I get:

```
[array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]])]
```

where as my desired output would be a single array of size 5x3, instead of two array 5x1 and 5x2

​If I try:

```
results=np.stack(list(map(lambda f:np.apply_along_axis(f,1, MATRIX),FUNCS)))
```

I get:

```
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Same with `np.vstack`, `np.hstack`

Comment: I use `np.apply_along_axis` on the third direction of a 4D volume, and store the resulting array (also 4D) in a `numpy` array. Could you do something similar?

Comment: You need to give a [mcve]

Comment: I am preparing that

Comment: I have added it

Comment: First make sure you understand what `apply...` is doing with each func.   `F_a` produces a (5,) array, `F_b` a (5,2).  It applies the func to each row, and collects the results in an array with the same first dimension, 5.  The second dimension depends on what the fun returns (scalar or 2 element list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With axis 1 and a 2d input, `apply_along_axis` just iterates on the rows (the other dimensions), and returns an array whose shape is determined by the iteration dimension, and the function value.

If the fn returns a scalar the result is just (5,), the size of the rows:

```
In [291]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda a1: 1, 1,arr)                                                     
Out[291]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [292]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[292]: (5,)
```

if it returns a list or single element array, that dimension is size 1:

```
In [293]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda a1: [1], 1,arr)                                                   
Out[293]: 
array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]])
In [294]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[294]: (5, 1)
```

And so on for other returns:

```
In [295]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda a1: np.arange(4), 1,arr)                                          
Out[295]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 2, 3]])
In [296]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[296]: (5, 4)
In [297]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda a1: a1, 1,arr)                                                    
Out[297]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
In [298]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[298]: (5, 3)
```

It's the same as making an array from a list comprenhension:

```
In [302]: [(lambda a1:1)(row) for row in arr]                                                          
Out[302]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
In [303]: [(lambda a1:[1,2])(row) for row in arr]                                                      
Out[303]: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

With 2d inputs like this `apply_along_axis` is little more than a notation convenience, if that.  For larger dimension that convenience is greater.  But it does not improve the speed over more direct iteration.

If  you don't understand `apply_along_axis`, or have problems using it, don't bother.  Do the kind of iteration that you understand.

====

If

```
def F_a(x):
    return [1]
```

your list map would produce (5,1) and (5,2) arrays, which could then be concatenated on the 2nd axis.

So besides have problems with `apply`, it looks like you aren't comfortable with `numpy` array dimensions, and how they control the use of `concatenate` (and the various `stack` variants).